# How to write the stored procedure query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to insert a new record into an `INVOICE` table

Details are:

- INVOICE (INV_NUMBER [PK, int], CUS_CODE [FK, int], INV_DATE [Date/time])
- CUSTOMER (CUS_CODE [PK], LNAME, FNAME, INITIAL, AREACODE, PHONE, BALANCE)

How do I go about writing the stored procedure query to insert a new row in `INVOICE` when there is a FK and int columns?

This is what i did, but is incorrect:

```
CREATE PROC spNewCustomer_INVOICE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @INV_NUMBER VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @CUS_CODE VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @INV_DATE VARCHAR(50);
AS 
    INSERT INTO INVOICE
    VALUES (@INV_NUMBER, @CUS_CODE, @INV_DATE)
```

Calling it:

```
EXEC spNewCustomer_INVOICE '2018', '20018', '2018-08-17'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what do you mean by `incorrect` ?

Comment: This is not the correct way of doing it. I am getting the following error messages:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spNewCustomer_INVOICE, Line 256
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spNewCustomer_INVOICE, Line 260
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure spNewCustomer_INVOICE, Line 264
Must declare the scalar variable "@INV_NUMBER".

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you need to create **parameters** for your stored procedure - not internal variables.

Secondly, I would **strongly recommend** using the **most appropriate datatype** for each parameter - not just `VARCHAR(50)` for everything. Your table's columns are of type `INT` and `DATETIME` - **use** those types for your parameters!

And thirdly, I recommend to always **explicitly specify** the columns of the target table you're inserting into.

So all in all - try this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewCustomerInvoice
    @INV_NUMBER INT,
    @CUS_CODE INT,
    @INV_DATE DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INVOICE (INV_NUMBER, CUS_CODE, INV_DATE)
    VALUES (@INV_NUMBER, @CUS_CODE, @INV_DATE);
END;
```

Then call this procedure with this command:

```
EXEC NewCustomerInvoice 
         @INV_NUMBER = 2018, 
         @CUS_CODE = 20018, 
         @INV_DATE = '20180817';
```

Comment: I would add explicit params with EXEC call: `EXEC NewCustomerInvoice  @INV_NUMBER =2018, @CUS_COD=20018, @INV_DATE='20180817';` and semicolon after each statement :)

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful! But when running the code I get the following error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure NewCustomerInvoice, Line 291
Incorrect syntax near '20180817'.

Comment: I would add explicit params with EXEC call: EXEC NewCustomerInvoice @INV_NUMBER =2018, @CUS_COD=20018, @INV_DATE='20180817'; - Tried this, Get the follwoing error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure NewCustomerInvoice, Line 291
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: INV_DATE format is  2006-01-16 00:00:00.000. Does this make a difference?

Comment: `INV_DATE` is a `DATETIME` in your database, which has **no format** - it's a 8-byte binary value

Comment: @HifzaRahim: see my updates - since you have a `BEGIN` in the procedure, you also need an `END` - added this. Please try again - I was able to run this `EXEC` just fine (SQL Server 2016)

Comment: @HifzaRahim: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.